# Video not playing in firefox

Tags: firefox

My youtube video is not displaying in firefox.

I want to uninstall firefox and install it again. How can I do.

Please help me do this..

Comment: What error are you getting while playing video in firefox?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install flash player.
Open a terminal by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and type the following:

```
sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer
```

You can also install google-chrome which comes with flash integration.

Answer (score 0):

Run these commands to install `Ubuntu restricted extras` which comes with flash and some other important packages:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```